# Is there an in-universe explanation why Picard uses shuttlecrafts instead of the Captain's Yacht?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, jean-luc-picard

There are numerous episodes of *Star Trek: TNG* where Captain Picard uses a shuttlecraft:

- Time Squared
- Samaritan Snare
- Liasons
- Final Mission
- Timescape
- Genesis

The *Enterprise-D* also has a Captain's Yacht, the *Calypso*.  According to [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Captain%27s_yacht), although it was portrayed on display screens, the set needed for filming it was never built due to budgetary costs.

**Is there an in-universe reason why Picard would use a shuttlecraft instead of his Captain's Yacht?**

Related:

- [What is the purpose of the Captain's Yacht on some Federation starship classes?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13770)
- [Did we ever see the captain's yacht?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/109585)
- [Is the Captain's Yacht from Enterprise-D (the Calypso) warp-capable?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/122146)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The largest reason comes from [that last question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/122146/is-the-captains-yacht-from-enterprise-d-the-calypso-warp-capable)

> The Calypso does not appear to have been warp capable.

Several times we see shuttlecraft being used to bridge long distances at warp (remember DS9's early seasons only had warp-capable shuttles as well). So it's likely that shuttles were the preferred mode of transport when the ship herself had to be somewhere else. This was more noticeable in later episodes like [Timescape](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Timescape_(episode)) where we see the shuttle go to warp (using a more DS9 styled shuttle instead of the old boxy white ones).

Comment: The DS9 craft you're thinking of are Danube-class Runabouts, and are in fact classed as ships (with their own registry) rather than shuttles. The craft featured in Timescape is in fact a Runabout too.